# pygame.colliderect for all Rects on screen

Tags: python, pygame

I am making my own version of bomberman, and was wondering if there was a way to have colliderect check for all Rect's on the screen, currently I have only managed to get it to work for one Rect at a time.
heres my code(note it is incomplete)
note what im trying to get the code to check for collisions with multiple 25x25 Rect's (the terrain squares) without checking for collision with each individual one.

```
import pygame
from sys import exit
import math
import random
import time
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

Dwidth = 1000
Dheight = 600

gameLoop = True

transparent = (0, 0, 0, 0)
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
sky = (213, 242, 246)
grey = (200,200,200)
dark_grey = (180,180,180)


gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((Dwidth,Dheight))
pygame.display.set_caption("Bomberman")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
clock.tick(30)

font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 64)

pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
Cursor = pygame.image.load("Bman_cursor.png").convert_alpha()

class terrain():
  def __init__(self, x, y, image, Type):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.image = image
    self.width = 25
    self.height = 25
    self.Type = Type
    self.collision = pygame.Rect(self.x,self.y, 24,24)
  def gety(self):
    return self.y
  
  def getx(self):
    return self.x

  def getype(self):
    return self.Type

  def draw(self, gameDisplay):
    gameDisplay.blit(self.image, (self.x,self.y))

  def newCoords(self, X, Y):
    self.x = X
    self.y = Y

    
class Player():
  def __init__(self, PlayerNO, Class, x, y):
    self.playerNO = PlayerNO
    self.Class = Class
    self.hp = 1
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.speed = 0.4
    self.bombNum = 1
    self.power = 1
    if self.Class == "Bomber":
      self.bombNum += 1
      self.ability = "bomb rush"
      self.image = pygame.image.load("Bman\white\Bman_idle.png")
    elif self.Class == "Chronomancer":
      self.ability = "time stop"
    elif self.Class == "Miner":
      self.power += 2
      self.ability =  "land mine"
      self.image = pygame.image.load("Bman\Black\Bman_black_idle.png")
    elif self.Class == "Racer":
      self.speed += 0.4 #0.2*2
      self.ability = "sprint"
    elif self.Class == "Strategist":
      pass
      #set bomb to time bomb
    else:
      print("CLASS ERROR")
    self.collision = pygame.Rect(self.x,self.y, 16,22)
  def getNO(self):
    return self.playerNO
  
  def getClass(self):
    return self.Class
  
  def gethp(self):
    return self.hp

  def getx(self):
    return self.x

  def gety(self):
    return self.y

  def getspeed(self):
    return self.speed

  def getbombNum(self):
    return self.bombNum

  def getpower(self):
    return self.power

  def move(self, direction):
    #Poverlap = self.collision.colliderect()#this is where i hope to check for collisions with all Rect's
    Poverlap = 0
    #print(Poverlap)
    if Poverlap == 1:
      pass
    elif Poverlap == 0:
      if direction == "left":
        if self.x > 275+self.speed:
          self.x -= self.speed
      elif direction == "up":
        if self.y > 77.5+self.speed:
          self.y -= self.speed
      elif direction == "right":
        if self.x < 712.5-self.speed:
          self.x += self.speed
      elif direction == "down":
        if self.y < 505.5-self.speed:
          self.y += self.speed
    else:
      print(Poverlap)
      print(Toverlap)
      print("overlap error")

  def newImage(self, image):
    self.image = image
    
  def draw(self):
    gameDisplay.blit(self.image, (self.x,self.y))

class bomb():
  pass


def createMap(grid, Bmap):
  GWstart = 250*(Dwidth/1000)
  GWend = 750*(Dwidth/1000)
  GHstart = 52.5*(Dheight/600)
  GHend = 552.5*(Dheight/600)
  GWpos = 25*(Dwidth/1000)
  GHpos = 25*(Dheight/600)
  if Bmap == 1:
    for x in range(3,7):
      grid[x][x] = 1
    y = 0
    for x in range(3,7):
      grid[16-y][x] = 1
      y += 1
    y = 0
    for x in range(3,7):
      grid[x][16-y] = 1
      y += 1
    y = 0
    for x in range(1,5):
      grid[16-y][16-y] = 1
      y += 1
    for x in range(3,6):
      grid[9][x] = 2
      grid[10][x] = 2
      grid[9][x+11] = 2
      grid[10][x+11] = 2
      grid[x][9] = 2
      grid[x][10] = 2
      grid[x+11][9] = 2
      grid[x+11][10] = 2
    for x in range (0,2):
      grid[7+x][6] = 2
      grid[9+x][6] = 1
      grid[11+x][6] = 2
      grid[9+x][7] = 1
      grid[12+x][7] = 2
      grid[9+x][8] = 2
      grid[13][8] = 2
      grid[6+x][9] = 1
      grid[8][9] = 2
      grid[12+x][9] = 1
      grid[11][9+x] = 2
      grid[12+x][10] = 1
      grid[7+x][13] = 2
      grid[9][13-x] = 1
      grid[13][11+x] = 2
      grid[9+x][11] = 2
      grid[10][13-x] = 1
      grid[11+x][13] = 2
      grid[6][7+x] = 2
      grid[6+x][9] = 1
      grid[8][9+x] = 2
      grid[6+x][10] = 1
      grid[6][11+x] = 2
      grid[7][7+5*x] = 2
      grid[9+x][9+x] = 2
      grid[9+x][10-x] = 2
      grid[2+10*x][2+10*x] = 2
      grid[17-15*x][2+15*x] = 2
      grid[8+3*x][16] = 1
      grid[16][8+3*x] = 1
      grid[3+5*x][8-5*x] = 1
      grid[11-8*x][3+8*x] = 1
    for x in range(0,3):
      grid[7-x][5-x] = 2
      grid[5-x][7-x] = 2
    for x in range(3,8):
      grid[x][2] = 1
      grid[2][x] = 1
      grid[x+9][2] = 1
      grid[2][x+9] = 1
      grid[17][x] = 1
      grid[x][17] = 1
      grid[17][x+9] = 1
      grid[x+9][17] = 1
    for x in range(0,3):
      grid[4+x][3+x] = 2
      grid[3+x][4+x] = 2
      grid[16-x][4+x] = 2
      grid[15-x][3+x] = 2
      grid[14-x][3+x] = 2
      grid[16-x][5+x] = 2
      grid[3+x][15-x] = 2
      grid[3+x][14-x] = 2
      grid[4+x][16-x] = 2
      grid[5+x][16-x] = 2
      grid[16-x][15-x] = 2
      grid[16-x][14-x] = 2
      grid[15-x][16-x] = 2
      grid[14-x][16-x] = 2
    grid[17][17] = 2
  elif Bmap == 2:
    for y in range(2,18,+3):
      for x in range(2,18,+3):
        grid[x][y] = 1
  elif Bmap == 3:
    for x in range (2,18):
      grid[2][x] = 1
      grid[x][2] = 1
    for x in range(4,18):
      grid[17][x] = 1
      grid[x][17] = 1
      if x < 17:
        grid[x][16] = 2
      if x < 16:
        grid[4][x] = 1
        grid[15][x] = 1
        grid[3][x] = 2
        grid[x][3] = 2
        grid[16][x] = 2
    for x in range(6,14):
      grid[6][x] = 1
      grid[8][x] = 1
      grid[9][x] = 2
      grid[10][x] = 2
      grid[11][x] = 1
      grid[13][x] = 1
    for x in range(5,14):
      grid[5][x] = 2
      grid[x][5] = 2
      grid[14][x] = 2
      grid[x][14] = 2
    for x in range(0,2):
      grid[17-14*x][3+14*x] = 2
      grid[16-14*x][2+14*x] = 2
      grid[3-x][2+x] = 2
      grid[16+x][17-x] = 2
    grid[16][16] = 0
    grid[14][14] = 2
  elif Bmap == 4:
    pass
  return grid


def CSelect(playerNum, backdrop):
  global Dwidth
  global Dheight
  global Cursor
  
  Bbomber = pygame.image.load("button_bomber.png")
  Bchrono = pygame.image.load("button_chronomancer.png")
  Bminer = pygame.image.load("button_miner.png")
  BRacer = pygame.image.load("button_racer.png")
  Bstrat = pygame.image.load("button_strategist.png")
  while True:
    gameDisplay.blit(backdrop, [0,0])
    gameDisplay.blit(Bbomber, [24, 230])
    gameDisplay.blit(Bchrono, [195, 230])
    gameDisplay.blit(Bminer, [435, 230])
    gameDisplay.blit(BRacer, [605, 230])
    gameDisplay.blit(Bstrat, [775, 230])
    gameDisplay.blit(Cursor, ( pygame.mouse.get_pos() ) )
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
          startButton = pygame.image.load("button_start.png")
          Map_select(startButton)
      elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.display.quit()
        pygame.quit()
        exit()
      elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        if event.pos[0] >= 24*(Dwidth/1000) and event.pos[0] <= 180*(Dwidth/1000) and event.pos[1] >= 230*(Dheight/600) and event.pos[1] <= 300*(Dheight/600):
          player1 = Player(playerNum, "Bomber", 300, 77.5)
          return player1
        if event.pos[0] >= 195*(Dwidth/1000) and event.pos[0] <= 420*(Dwidth/1000) and event.pos[1] >= 230*(Dheight/600) and event.pos[1] <= 300*(Dheight/600):
          player1 = Player(playerNum, "Chronomancer", 300, 77.5)
          return player1
        if event.pos[0] >= 435*(Dwidth/1000) and event.pos[0] <= 580*(Dwidth/1000) and event.pos[1] >= 230*(Dheight/600) and event.pos[1] <= 300*(Dheight/600):
          player1 = Player(playerNum, "Miner", 300, 77.5)
          return player1
        if event.pos[0] >= 605*(Dwidth/1000) and event.pos[0] <= 760*(Dwidth/1000) and event.pos[1] >= 230*(Dheight/600) and event.pos[1] <= 300*(Dheight/600):
          player1 = Player(playerNum, "Racer", 300, 77.5)
          return player1
        if event.pos[0] >= 775*(Dwidth/1000) and event.pos[0] <= 970*(Dwidth/1000) and event.pos[1] >= 230*(Dheight/600) and event.pos[1] <= 300*(Dheight/600):
          player1 = Player(playerNum, "Strategist", 300, 77.5)
          return player1
    pygame.display.update()

def preGame(backdrop):
  global Dwidth
  global Dheight
  global Cursor

  singleButton = pygame.image.load("button_single-player.png")
  multiButton = pygame.image.load("button_multiplayer.png")

  while True:
    gameDisplay.blit(backdrop, [0,0])
    gameDisplay.blit(singleButton, [190, 280])
    gameDisplay.blit(multiButton, [555, 280])
    gameDisplay.blit(Cursor, ( pygame.mouse.get_pos() ) )
    for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
          return 3
      elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.display.quit()
        pygame.quit()
        exit()
      elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        if event.pos[0] >= 190*(Dwidth/1000) and event.pos[0] <= 445*(Dwidth/1000) and event.pos[1] >= 280*(Dheight/600) and event.pos[1] <= 350*(Dheight/600):
          playerNum = 1
          return playerNum
        elif event.pos[0] >= 555*(Dwidth/1000) and event.pos[0] <= 710*(Dwidth/1000) and event.pos[1] >= 280*(Dheight/600) and event.pos[1] <= 350*(Dheight/600):
          playerNum = 2
          return playerNum
    pygame.display.update()


def inGame(backdrop, Bmap):
  global Dwidth
  global Dheight
  global cursor
  playerNum = preGame(backdrop)
  if playerNum == 3:
    return
  if playerNum == 1:
    player1 = CSelect(1, backdrop)
  elif playerNum == 2:
    player1 = CSelect(1, backdrop)
    player2 = CSelect(2, backdrop)
  grid = []
  for row in range(20):
    grid.append([])
    for column in range(20):
        grid[row].append(0) #gives me a 20x20 grid for the game processes
  for x in range (20):
      grid[x][0] = 1
      grid[0][x] = 1
      grid[19][x] = 1
      grid[x][19] = 1 #1 = hard terrain, 2 = soft terrain and 0 = no terrain
  
  gameDisplay.blit(backdrop, [0,0])
  Lterrain = pygame.image.load("soft_terrain.png")
  Hterrain = pygame.image.load("hard_terrain.png")

  GWstart = 250*(Dwidth/1000)
  GWend = 750*(Dwidth/1000)
  GHstart = 52.5*(Dheight/600)
  GHend = 552.5*(Dheight/600)
  GWpos = 25*(Dwidth/1000)
  GHpos = 25*(Dheight/600)

  Lgrass = (17, 191, 60)
  Dgrass = (2, 162, 36)
  DVrock = (130,0,0)
  LVrock = (180,30,30)
  Lrock = (159,105,52)
  Drock = (116,77,38)
  Lsky = (240,250,255)
  Dsky = (178,232,255)
  
  dark_light = 0
  grid = createMap(grid, Bmap)
  if Bmap == 1:
    Lcolour = LVrock
    Dcolour = DVrock
    base = pygame.image.load("Volcano_base.png")
  elif Bmap == 2:
    Lcolour = Lgrass
    Dcolour = Dgrass
    base = pygame.image.load("Forest_base.png")
  elif Bmap == 3:
    Lcolour = Lrock
    Dcolour = Drock
    base = pygame.image.load("Cave_base.png")
  elif Bmap == 4:
    Lcolour = Lsky
    Dcolour = Dsky
    base = pygame.image.load("Sky_base.png")

  gameDisplay.blit(backdrop, [0,0])
  Lcounter = 0
  Ucounter = 0
  Rcounter = 0
  Dcounter = 0
  transparent = (0, 0, 0, 0)
  gameDisplay.blit(base, [GWstart, GHstart])
  HRterrain = terrain(GWstart+GWpos-25,GHstart + GHpos -25, Hterrain, 1)
  LIterrain = terrain(GWstart+GWpos-25,GHstart + GHpos -25, Lterrain, 2)
  print(player1.getx())
  print(player1.gety())
  while True:
    gameDisplay.blit(base, [GWstart, GHstart])
    for x in range(len(grid)):
      for y in range(len(grid[0])):
        if grid[x][y] == 1:
          HRterrain.newCoords(GWstart+GWpos-25, GHstart + GHpos -25)
          pygame.Rect(GWstart+GWpos-25, GHstart+GHpos-25, 25,25)
          HRterrain.draw(gameDisplay)
        elif grid[x][y] == 2:
          LIterrain.newCoords(GWstart+GWpos-25, GHstart + GHpos -25)
          pygame.Rect(GWstart+GWpos-25, GHstart+GHpos-25, 25,25)
          LIterrain.draw(gameDisplay)
        GWpos += 25
      GWpos = 25
      GHpos += 25
    GHpos = 25
    for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
          return
      elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.display.quit()
        pygame.quit()
        exit()
    #moves 11.999999999999318 pixels per 30 counter
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key[K_a]:
      Lcounter += 1
      player1.move("left")
      if Lcounter < 30:
        if player1.getClass() == "Miner":
          player1.newImage(pygame.image.load("Bman\Black\Bman_black_left1.png"))
      elif Lcounter == 30:
        if player1.getClass() == "Miner":
          player1.newImage(pygame.image.load("Bman\Black\Bman_black_left2.png"))
      elif Lcounter == 60:
        if player1.getClass() == "Miner":
          player1.newImage(pygame.image.load("Bman\Black\Bman_black_left1.png"))
      elif Lcounter == 90:
        if player1.getClass() == "Miner":
          player1.newImage(pygame.image.load("Bman\Black\Bman_black_left3.png"))
      elif Lcounter == 120:
        if player1.getClass() == "Miner":
          player1.newImage(pygame.image.load("Bman\Black\Bman_black_left1.png"))
        Lcounter = 0
    elif key[K_w]:
      Ucounter += 1
      player1.move("up")
      if Ucounter < 30:
        if player1.getClass() == "Miner":
          player1.newImage(pygame.image.load("Bman\Black\Bman_black_up1.png"))
      elif Ucounter == 30:
        if player1.getClass() == "Miner":
          player1.newImage(pygame.image.load("Bman\Black\Bman_black_up2.png"))
      elif Ucounter == 60:
        if player1.getClass() == "Miner":
          player1.newImage(pygame.image.load("Bman\Black\Bman_black_up1.png"))
      elif Ucounter == 90:
        if player1.getClass() == "Miner":
          player1.newImage(pygame.image.load("Bman\Black\Bman_black_up3.png"))
      elif Ucounter == 120:
        if player1.getClass() == "Miner":
          player1.newImage(pygame.image.load("Bman\Black\Bman_black_up1.png"))
        Ucounter = 0
    elif key[K_d]:
      player1.move("right")
      Rcounter += 1
      if Rcounter < 30:
        if player1.getClass() == "Miner":
          player1.newImage(pygame.transform.flip(pygame.image.load("Bman\Black\Bman_black_left1.png"), True, False))
      elif Rcounter == 30:
        if player1.getClass() == "Miner":
          player1.newImage(pygame.transform.flip(pygame.image.load("Bman\Black\Bman_black_left2.png"), True, False))
      elif Rcounter == 60:
        if player1.getClass() == "Miner":
          player1.newImage(pygame.transform.flip(pygame.image.load("Bman\Black\Bman_black_left1.png"), True, False))
      elif Rcounter == 90:
        if player1.getClass() == "Miner":
          player1.newImage(pygame.transform.flip(pygame.image.load("Bman\Black\Bman_black_left3.png"), True, False))
      elif Rcounter == 120:
        if player1.getClass() == "Miner":
          player1.newImage(pygame.transform.flip(pygame.image.load("Bman\Black\Bman_black_left1.png"), True, False))
        Rcounter = 0
    elif key[K_s]:
      player1.move("down")
      Dcounter += 1
      if Dcounter < 30:
        player1.newImage(pygame.image.load("Bman\Black\Bman_black_idle.png"))
      elif Dcounter == 30:
        player1.newImage(pygame.image.load("Bman\Black\Bman_black_forward_redo.png"))
      elif Dcounter == 60:
        player1.newImage(pygame.image.load("Bman\Black\Bman_black_idle.png"))
      elif Dcounter == 90:
        player1.newImage(pygame.image.load("Bman\Black\Bman_black_forward2.png"))
      elif Dcounter == 120:
        player1.newImage(pygame.image.load("Bman\Black\Bman_black_idle.png"))
        Dcounter = 0
      
    player1.draw()  
    pygame.display.update()
    


def Map_select(startButton):
  global Dwidth
  global Dheight
  backButton = pygame.image.load("button_back.png")
  Volcano_zone = pygame.image.load("Volcano zone.png")
  Volcano_zone = pygame.transform.smoothscale(Volcano_zone, (Dwidth, Dheight))
  Forest_zone = pygame.image.load("Forest zone.jpg")
  Forest_zone = pygame.transform.smoothscale(Forest_zone, (Dwidth, Dheight))
  Cave_zone = pygame.image.load("Cave_zone.jpg")
  Cave_zone = pygame.transform.smoothscale(Cave_zone, (Dwidth, Dheight))
  Sky_zone = pygame.image.load("Sky_zone.png")
  Sky_zone = pygame.transform.smoothscale(Sky_zone, (Dwidth, Dheight))
  Right_button = pygame.image.load("Right_arrow.png")
  Left_button = pygame.image.load("Left_arrow.png")
  Bmap = 1
  while True:
    if Bmap == 1:
      gameDisplay.blit(Volcano_zone, [0,0])
    elif Bmap == 2:
      gameDisplay.blit(Forest_zone, [0,0])
    elif Bmap == 3:
      gameDisplay.blit(Cave_zone, [0,0])
    elif Bmap == 4:
      gameDisplay.blit(Sky_zone, [0,0])
    elif Bmap == 5:
      Bmap = 1
      gameDisplay.blit(Volcano_zone, [0,0])
    elif Bmap == 0:
      Bmap = 4
      gameDisplay.blit(Sky_zone, [0,0])
    gameDisplay.blit(Left_button, [50*(Dwidth/1000), 500*(Dheight/600)])
    gameDisplay.blit(Right_button, [810*(Dwidth/1000), 500*(Dheight/600)])
    gameDisplay.blit(backButton, [439.5*(Dwidth/1000), 510*(Dheight/600)])
    gameDisplay.blit(startButton, (100*(Dwidth/1000), 75*(Dheight/600)))
    gameDisplay.blit( Cursor, ( pygame.mouse.get_pos() ) )
    pygame.display.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
          main_menu()
      elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.display.quit()
        pygame.quit()
        exit()
      elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        if event.pos[0] >= 50*(Dwidth/1000) and event.pos[0] <= 240*(Dwidth/1000) and event.pos[1] >= 500*(Dheight/600) and event.pos[1] <= 570*(Dheight/600):
          Bmap -= 1
          print("-1")
        elif event.pos[0] >= 810*(Dwidth/1000) and event.pos[0] <= 950*(Dwidth/1000) and event.pos[1] >= 500*(Dheight/600) and event.pos[1] <= 570*(Dheight/600):
          Bmap += 1
          print("+1")
        elif event.pos[0] >= 439.5*(Dwidth/1000) and event.pos[0] <= 560.5*(Dwidth/1000) and event.pos[1] >= 500*(Dheight/600) and event.pos[1] <= 550*(Dheight/600):
          main_menu()
        elif event.pos[0] >= 100*(Dwidth/1000) and event.pos[0] <= 265*(Dwidth/1000) and event.pos[1] >= 75*(Dheight/600) and event.pos[1] <= 155*(Dheight/600):
          if Bmap == 1:
            inGame(Volcano_zone,Bmap)
          elif Bmap == 2:
            inGame(Forest_zone,Bmap)
          elif Bmap == 3:
            inGame(Cave_zone,Bmap)
          elif Bmap == 4:
            inGame(Sky_zone,Bmap)
          else:
            print("error")
          
  

def settings_menu(Fwidth, Fheight, background_image):
  global Dwidth
  global Dheight
  global gameDisplay
  gameDisplay.blit(background_image, [0,0])
  Settloop = True
  resButton = pygame.image.load("button_resolution.png")
  gameDisplay.blit(resButton, [100,275])
  backButton = pygame.image.load("button_back.png")
  gameDisplay.blit(backButton, [100, 475])
  cntrlsButton = pygame.image.load("button_controls.png")
  gameDisplay.blit(cntrlsButton, [365, 275])
  while Settloop is True:
    clock.tick(60)
    background_image = pygame.transform.smoothscale(background_image, (Dwidth, Dheight))
    gameDisplay.blit(background_image, [0,0])
    gameDisplay.blit(resButton, [100*(Dwidth/1000),275*(Dheight/600)])
    gameDisplay.blit(cntrlsButton, [375*(Dwidth/1000), 275*(Dheight/600)])
    gameDisplay.blit(backButton, [100*(Dwidth/1000), 475*(Dheight/600)])
    gameDisplay.blit(Cursor, ( pygame.mouse.get_pos() ) )
    for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        if event.pos[0] >= 100*(Dwidth/1000) and event.pos[0] <= 345*(Dwidth/1000) and event.pos[1] >= 275*(Dheight/600) and event.pos[1] <= 355*(Dheight/600):
          print("Current resolution:", Dwidth, "x", Dheight, "\nEnter a new resolution or enter 0 to pass\n*NOTE*: some resolutions may make the game unplayable as the game is built around the default resolution\nincreasing the resolution will also in turn decrease the framerate")
          newWidth = int(input("New width: "))
          newHeight = int(input("New height: "))
          if newHeight <= 0 or newWidth <= 0:
            pass
          else:
            #print("hit escape to apply changes")
            Dwidth = newWidth
            Dheight = newHeight
            gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((Dwidth,Dheight)) #changes the resolution of the game window
        elif event.pos[0] >= 100*(Dwidth/1000) and event.pos[0] <= 221*(Dwidth/1000) and event.pos[1] >= 475*(Dheight/600) and event.pos[1] <= 525*(Dheight/600):
          return
        elif event.pos[0] >= 365*(Dwidth/1000) and event.pos[0] <= 575*(Dwidth/1000) and event.pos[1] >= 275*(Dheight/600) and event.pos[1] <= 355*(Dheight/600):
          print("\nP1:\n Movement: WASD\n Place Bomb: Y\n Usable powerup(e.g time bomb): U\n Use Class ability: I") #prints controls into console
          print("\nP2:\n Movement: Arrow  keys\n Place bomb: Numberpad 1(N1)\n Usable powerup(e.g time bomb): N2\n Use Class ability: N3")
      elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
          return #returns to main menu
      elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.display.quit()
        pygame.quit()
        exit()
      pygame.display.flip()

def main_menu():
  background_image = pygame.image.load("Title_Background.jpg")
  background_image = pygame.transform.smoothscale(background_image, (Dwidth, Dheight))
  gameDisplay.blit(background_image, [0,0])
  startButton = pygame.image.load("button_start.png")
  gameDisplay.blit(startButton, [100,275])
  settingsButton = pygame.image.load("button_settings.png")
  gameDisplay.blit(settingsButton, [100,375])
  #tester = pygame.image.load("Bman/Black/Bman__test.png")
  clock.tick(60)
  while gameLoop is True:
      clock.tick(60)
      gameDisplay.blit(background_image, [0,0])
      gameDisplay.blit(settingsButton, [100*(Dwidth/1000),375*(Dheight/600)])
      gameDisplay.blit(startButton, [100*(Dwidth/1000),275*(Dheight/600)])
      gameDisplay.blit( Cursor, ( pygame.mouse.get_pos() ) )
      #gameDisplay.blit(tester, [10,10])
      pygame.display.update()
      for event in pygame.event.get():
          if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.pos[0] >= 100*(Dwidth/1000) and event.pos[0] <= 265*(Dwidth/1000) and event.pos[1] >= 275*(Dheight/600) and event.pos[1] <= 355*(Dheight/600):
              Map_select(startButton)
            elif event.pos[0] >= 100*(Dwidth/1000) and event.pos[0] <= 300*(Dwidth/1000) and event.pos[1] >= 375*(Dheight/600) and event.pos[1] <= 455*(Dheight/600):#the *(Dheight/600) and *(Dwidth/1000) are to make sure the buttons scale with resolution when it changes
              settings_menu(Dwidth, Dheight, background_image)
#          print(event.pos[0])#event.pos[0] = x-coords
#          print(event.pos[1])#event.pos[1] = y-coords
#          print(event.pos)#event.pos = (x-coords, y-coords)  i use these to check coords when setting up buttons
          if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
              pygame.display.quit()
              pygame.quit()
              exit()#exits the game
          elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.display.quit()
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
          pygame.display.flip()
main_menu()
```

Comment: I recommend to use the [`pygame.sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) module (`Sprite`, `Group`, `spritecollide()`). Anyway, there is also [`pygame.Rect.collidelist()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidelist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `rect.collidelist(list)` and pass in a list of rects.

I'm pretty sure that all `collidelist()` does is iterate through the list of rects, similar to what you're currently doing, but I'd recommend looking at the [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidelist) if you have any further questions.

Comment: @Patrick Cole If it's the correct answer, please mark the answer as accepted, in order to help others who see this question.